# How to secure plain text Password in python script

Tags: python, macos

I have a Python script that contains a plain text password used to bind Mac to AD.
I need to deploy this script to few Macs.

How can I secure password which is in plain text, so that no one can see the password?

I don't want to use `base64`, I'd need something stronger than `base64`.

Comment: You should avoid strong any security credentials in the source code. Use environment variables instead.

Comment: Even if you make sure the password never appears in the source code, what's stopping your user from editing the program to add `print(password)` right after your `password = retrieve_password_from_secure_storage()` line?

Comment: @Kevin You can edit any program, be it executable or not, to do that. It's just simpler with an interpreted language. Even if a program tries to check its own checksum you can just modify the code so that it skips that check. The only way to prevent program modification would be to use a digital signature of the code and have the kernel verify the signature before running it. And even then, you are running the kernel in the attackers' environmnet so they can just add their certificate to the OS trust store and sign the modified code...

Comment: Each user gets its own AD account and enters its own password from command line or stores it via env var or keyring or whatever. Why sharing credentials for multiple users, anyway?

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning - `base64` is not an _encryption_ mechanism. It's an _encoding_ scheme. Simply put, it translates binary data (like images) to text so that the resulting text contains only ASCII characters, and vice versa. It doesn't encrypt anything at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try storing the password in a variable in a separate Python script.

pass.py

`password = 'PASSWORD'`

Import the variable from this script separately.

main.py

`from pass import password`

This will create a bytecode file named pass.pyc. Now you can delete pass.py and continue using pass.pyc, which isn't human-readable and much harder to decompile.

Edit: If somebody has access to your source code, they can still see the password with a print statement!

Edit 2: As Giacomo Alzetta commented, the password is still human-readable here, but it comes down to the "attack model" here. If someone really wants to, they can still dig around and find it. Other alternatives are encryption algorithms available in OpenSSL. Symmetric key algorithms might still not be useful for you since you'd probably have to store the encryption key within the source code. Asymmetric key algorithms might work.

Comment: `$ echo 'PASSWORD="HELLO"' > a.py && python3 -c 'import a' && cat __pycache__/a.*.pyc
3
ip,]�@dZdS)ZHELLON)PASSWORD�rr� /tmp/a.py<module>s` The password is clearly human readable inside `.pyc` files. Please don't suggest using bytecode to "hide" passwords

Answer (score -1):

You can use encode and decode functions.

```py
def encode(key, clear):
    enc = []
    for i in range(len(clear)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        enc_c = chr((ord(clear[i]) + ord(key_c)) % 256)
        enc.append(enc_c)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode("".join(enc).encode()).decode()

def decode(key, enc):
    dec = []
    enc = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc).decode()
    for i in range(len(enc)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        dec_c = chr((256 + ord(enc[i]) - ord(key_c)) % 256)
        dec.append(dec_c)
    return "".join(dec)
```

Usage: `encode("mykey", "password")`

(You need to import base64)

If you want high secured password, i coded a script but i tried to decode the string and i can not do it.

Comment: Both the "decode" function and key would be part of the source-code here, so anyone who has access to the source-code can still figure out the password with a function call.